# different representation of arrays in chrome console

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, async-await, console.log

Here is my code

```
let loadInitialImages = ($) => {
 let html = "";
 let images = new Array();
 const APIURL = "https://api.shutterstock.com/v2/images/licenses";

 const request = async() => {
    const response = await fetch(APIURL, { headers: auth_header() } );
    const json = await response.json();
    json.data.map((v) => images.push(v.image.id)); //this is where the problem is
 }

 request();

 // I can see the contents of the array when I log it.
 console.log(images);
 // But I can't see any elements when logging this way:
 images.map((id) => console.log(id));
}
```

Everything is working fine here but the problem is when I'm pushing the elements into the array is goes out of the array braces `[]` below is the screenshot of my array:
[image: Array output]

I'm not able to loop through the array here.

This is how a usual Array looks like in Console
[image: Usual Array]

See Array braces here. Elements appear to be inside `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"goes out of the array braces"*? Your array screenshot looks fine to me.

Comment: images = json.data.map((v) => v.image.id);

Comment: you're not waiting for the request to finish. You need to `await request();` before you `console.log(images);`

Comment: When you call `console.log(images)`, `images` is empty and then `request` populates it - that's why you can expand it and see ids

Comment: @adiga this is exactly what I was thinking until I compared it with an usual array. See the Updated question.

Comment: And if it seems okay. then, why I'm not able to loop trough the array

Comment: you should ad the code where "you are not able to loop through the array" to your question.

Comment: @lucascaro See the last commented line of the function

Comment: did you check the answers? seems that you're trying to use the result of an `async` function before it's ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `request` function is `async` you need to treat its result as a `Promise`.

This is also the reason why you see it represented differently in the chrome console. An empty array gets printed, but the references in the console are updated dynamically, so you can still expand it and see the contents.

If you want to log the contents of the array statically, you could use something like `JSON.stringify` to print it. This will print a string representation of the exact state of the array at the time of logging.

```js
// You will need to check the output in the browser console.
// Your code could be reduced to this:
const a = []; 
setTimeout(() => a.push(1, 2), 100); 
console.log('a:', a);

// A filled array logs differently:
const b = [1, 2]; 
console.log('b:', b);

// Stringify gives you a fixed state:
const c = []; 
setTimeout(() => c.push(1, 2), 100);
console.log('c:', JSON.stringify(c));
```

Regarding your code, on top of waiting for `request()`, if you are using `map` you should take advantage [of how it works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). You can use it to generate your entire array without using `push` for example. If you still want to use your array and `push()` to it, you should use `json.data.forEach` instead of `json.data.map` since it doesn't duplicate the array.

```
// Making your function `async` so you can `await` for the `request()`
let loadInitialImages = async ($) => {
  let html = "";
  const APIURL = "https://api.shutterstock.com/v2/images/licenses";

  const request = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(APIURL, { headers: auth_header() } );
    const json = await response.json();
    // Array.map will return a new array with the results of applying 
    // the given function to the original array, you can use that as 
    // an easy way to return your desired array.
    return json.data.map((v) => v.image.id); 
  }

  // Since request() is async, you need to wait for it to complete.
  const images = await request();
  // Array.forEach lets you iterate over an array without generating a
  // copy. If you use map here, you would be making an unneeded copy 
  // of your images array.
  images.forEach(i => console.log(i));
}
```

Comment: No, I'm not confused with the representation. The problem here is I'm not able to loop through the Array.

Comment: Updated to address what I think was the actual question: what is chrome doing with this array?

Comment: Yeah exactly. this was my problem. People are downvoting the questions without even understanding the actual problem

Answer (score -1):

Snippet below demonstrates your issue (your case is `arr1`, you want `arr2`). 
In case `loadInitialImages` can't be `async` use `arr3` scenario.

```js
async function main(){
let arr1 = [], arr2 = [], arr3 = [];

const getArray = ()=> (new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(()=>{resolve([1,2,3])},1000)))



async function request(arr, number){
  var result = await getArray();
  result.forEach((el)=>(arr.push(el)))
  console.log(`inner${number}`, arr)
  return result;
}

request(arr1, 1);

console.log("outer1", arr1)

await request(arr2, 2);

console.log("outer2", arr2)

request(arr3, 3).then(()=>{
  console.log("then3",arr3)
})
console.log("outer3", arr3)
}

main();
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the probleme is that the console.log() is fired before the array is populated, and becose the console.log work with reference it print both state of array (when it's empty, and after populating it with .map)

you can test this code ?
the console is directly after the loop

```
let loadInitialImages = ($) => {
    let html = "";
    let images = new Array();
    const APIURL = "https://api.shutterstock.com/v2/images/licenses";

    const request = async() => {
       const response = await fetch(APIURL, { headers: auth_header() } );
       const json = await response.json();
       json.data.map((v) => images.push(v.image.id)); //this is where the problem is
       console.log(images);
    }

    request();

}
```

```js
let loadInitialImages = ($) => {
        let html = "";
        let images = new Array();
        const APIURL = "https://api.shutterstock.com/v2/images/licenses";

        const request = async() => {
           const response = await fetch(APIURL, { headers: auth_header() } );
           const json = await response.json();
           json.data.map((v) => images.push(v.image.id)); //this is where the problem is
           console.log(images);
        }

        request();

    }
    
    loadInitialImages();
```